# After PHC hours were extended, we observed a reduction in ER visits for non-urgent care: how to determine causality?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, causality

I am from a Caribbean Island.
Data was collected from the ER regarding visits for non-urgent care by residents of a rural area.
In 2014, the total number of visits = 2,197.
In 2015, the total number of visits = 701.
In 2015, the public health clinic extended hours from 8 am - 1 pm to 8 am - 9 pm.
How do I determine, statistically, causality?

Comment: Before you get to causality, I'd first verify/establish that the 2015 number of visits is statistically different from the prior years. To do that, you'd like some data going further back so you can look at what's normal variability.

If the number is consistently near 2000 then it drops to 700, that strongly suggests *something* is different about 2015, but what precisely causes the difference may not be answerable using the data. Eg. if multiple things changed in 2015, it may be difficult or impossible to say how much is from extended clinic hours vs. how much is from something else.

Comment: Do you have data on the types of cases admitted to the ER? If the number of serious cases stays constant from 2014 to 2015 but the number of unserious cases declines dramatically, that might strongly suggest that less serious cases were instead going to the clinic...  In this type of problem, you're probably not going to be able to show causality in the classic, controlled drug trial sense, but you can still build a compelling case, try to rule out any plausible story besides people substituting the clinic for the ER.